# Let's talk about our tags again

Tags: discussion, tags

This may turn into a series of Meta posts. This is part 1.

The [first round](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/lets-talk-about-tag-wikis) of tag improvements took place back in February. One of the [responses](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1250/78) from that discussion mentioned that our tagging structure doesn't feel quite right:

> Most of our tags date from the time we were Moderators, not Community Building, and I often feel like I can't quite find the right tags for a question -- but if I knew what tags we needed I'd just make them.

In the last couple questions there have been a few discussions about appropriate tags to utilize.

- [Should the avatar of an organization in social networks be its logo?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/should-the-avatar-of-an-organization-in-social-networks-be-its-logo) In this question I created two new tags based on feedback from the post author. [social-network](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-network) and [volunteers](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volunteers) were created and populated with an initial wiki excerpt. There was a request for a few others:

  - [interactions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactions) - Instead of creating this tag, I applied the [user-engagement](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-engagement). However, that feels odd. I wasn't happy with "interactions" though, either. Suggestions?
  - [logo](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logo) - I did not create this tag. It feels very specific. However, a more general "design" type tag does feel relevant. I'm kind of surprised we haven't gotten more design/layout type questions.
- [Electing one person versus electing several: are the considerations for choosing a voting scheme different?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/electing-one-person-versus-electing-several-are-the-considerations-for-choosing) The author mentions they are not entirely pleased with the tag provided (or the possible synonym). They were unable to find a tag that feels appropriate, and I haven't come up with any better ideas. When you look at this question, how do *you* think it should be tagged?

Other than the two questions above, what are your experiences when tagging on Community Building? Do you struggle to find the tags you think should fit the question? If so, can you provide an example so that we can fix it? Let's take another pass at cleaning up our tags or adding new ones that are relevant.

Comment: I disagree with a design tag since that's very broad. Something like user experience or avatar would be a better choice.

Comment: I think of "design" as being about site design, but the avatar question is about *using* a site, not *building* it.  One concept in play there is "branding".  Another is the graphical representation of a user, but I don't have a good idea for a tag name there.  Like "gravatar" but not that (as that implies a specific implementation).

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin, You're right, I was going for more of a "user experience" than design in general.

Comment: The Electing... question deserves the *Voting* tag (I have added it), and I would suggest that *Voting* gets a synonym *Election* (or maybe *Electing*, but that's less used).

Comment: Instead of the "interactions" tag, we could use a "communication" or "user-communication" tag. However, I think "user-engagement" can cover the topic. The question is about creating engagement - user should participate in the community.